# append textbox value to textarea on enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the <kbd>enter</kbd> button is pressed, I'd like the `textbox` value to be appended on a new line to a `textarea`. I've already got the <kbd>enter</kbd> working but I'm not sure how to append the `textbox` value. I tried something but it didn't work.

```
$(function() {
    $("#quickLinksTextbox input").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            $("#quickLinksURLs").val().append("#quickLinksSave");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my code.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hcxsvefu/)

```
$(document).on('keypress', '#quickLinksTextbox input', function (e){

    var inputEl = $(this);
    var textareaEl = $('#quickLinksURLs');

    //Enter was pressed
    if(e.keyCode == 13){

        //If input have any text
        if($(inputEl).val().length){

            //Appending current content from input (with new line ending) to textarea
            $(textareaEl).val($(textareaEl).val()+$(inputEl).val()+"\r\n");

            //Cleaning input
            $(inputEl).val('');
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

To append data to the value, get the old value, append the data to the string, then assign the new value back.

```
$("#quickLinksURLs").val(
    $("#quickLinksURLs").val() + $("#quickLinksSave").val()
);
```

You will probably want to add `+ "\n"` somewhere in that string to get your new line.

Comment: @blex when I use your code my textarea text just disappears.. 
Edit: It works now, you used `quickLinksURLs` instead of `quickLinksSave`. Thanks +1