# Add/Remove Textbox Value from Textarea

Tags: jquery

I'm going off this existing example on StackOverflow, which simply adds a textbox value to a textarea as a new line with some accompanying text.

I modified it to work via onChange however, and am adding multiple textboxes that will each add new lines if there is a value present; all works fine:

```
$(document).on('change', '#dlnum input', function (e){

    var inputEl = $(this);
    var textareaEl = $('#BoloDesc');

        //If input has any text
        if($(inputEl).val().length){

            //Appending line to textarea
            $(textareaEl).val($(textareaEl).val()+'DL NUMBER'+' '+$(inputEl).val()+"\r\n");

        return false;
    }

});
```

All this works fine; my question is, just as the textbox value is added or appended to the textarea when a value exists in that textbox, I'd like for the textarea to *remove that particular textbox value from the textarea when it's empty*.

I know Googling this brings up setting .val='', but of course this will clear out the entire textarea, which isn't what I want to do. I simply want to *remove that particular textbox value while keeping all of the others in there*.

How can I do this?

Original StackOverflow post is here:
[append textbox value to textarea on enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28905022/append-textbox-value-to-textarea-on-enter)

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Use regex and replace that particular data from textarea

Answer (score 1):

I would declare a global array called

```
var content = [];
```

Then when the `change` event gets fired I would add the content of the input box to a specific index(same input always to the same index), like:

```
$(document).on('change', '#dlnum input', function (e){
    content['dl_number'] = $(this).val();
    render();  
});
```

After the content has been set in the array, each `change` event should call the `render` function which would combine the content of the array and should modify the content of the textarea.

```
function render(){
    var text = "";
    for (var x in content) {
       text += content[x] ? content[x] + "\r\n" : "";
    }
    $('#BoloDesc').val(text);
}
```

Comment: This seems easy enough, sounds like what I need, however, the content['dl_number']....what is that referencing? dlnum_input is my textbox, BoloDesc is my textarea...thanks a ton for the help by the way!

EDIT: sorry no, dlnum is the DIV that input is wrapped in. The actual id of the textbox isn't referenced anywhere.

Comment: dl_number is just an internal identifier, you can change it to whatever you would like as soon as it's unique for each input. "#BoloDesc" is the id of the textarea, "#dlnum input" references the input box (you have used this in your example, thats why I used the same reference) which is identified in the array as dl_number.

Comment: Hmm I've got the JS setup like this:

`<script type="text/javascript">
var content = [];

$(document).on('change', '#dlnum input', function (e){
    content['dl_number'] = $(this).val();
    render();  
});

function render(){
    var text = "";
    $.each(content, function( index, value ) {
        text += value ? value + "\r\n" : "";
    });
    $('#BoloDesc').val(text);
}
</script>`

Comment: Referencing the following HTML below:

`<div id="dlnum"><span class="srch_title">Driver License:</span><br />
<cfinput name="Bolo_DLNum" id="Bolo_DLNum" type="text" class="inputs_nomargin_lg" maxlength="50" onFocus="this.className='inputs_nomargin_lg_highlight'" onBlur="this.className='inputs_nomargin_lg'" value="#session.bolo_driverlicense#"></div>`

Doesn't appear to work?

Comment: Change this from `$(document).on('change', '#dlnum input', function (e)` to `$(document).on('change', '#Bolo_DLNum', function (e)` and it should work.

Comment: I'm running it through Fiddle to play around with it a bit more, so far that didn't change anything

Comment: Looks like there was a problem with the jquery each function, I used the javascript alternative, check out the demo here: http://jsbin.com/yoxefayosa/3/edit

Comment: Thanks for the help! it works perfectly in jsbin, and on my hard drive, but no matter what, I can't get it to work on my server..I've tried different internal/external references to the jQuery library, to no avail.

I'm going to go a different direction and try some other code I've got working, that just needs an if/then component added to it, maybe that's the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just checking if that value is present in the textarea, if it's present then am removing it via array `splice` method.

```
$("#delete").on("click", function() {
  var value = $("#quickLinksTextbox input").val();  
  var textareaEl = $('#quickLinksURLs');
  var textareavalue = textareaEl.val().split("\n");
  if(textareavalue.indexOf(value) >= 0) {
     textareavalue.splice(textareavalue.indexOf(value),1);
     textareaEl.val(textareavalue.join("\n"));
  }
});
```

Here is the full demo:

```js
$(document).on('keypress', '#quickLinksTextbox input', function (e){
   
var inputEl = $(this);
var textareaEl = $('#quickLinksURLs');

//Enter was pressed
if(e.keyCode == 13){
     
    //If input have any text
    if($(inputEl).val().length){
        
        //Appending word (with ending new line) to textarea
        $(textareaEl).val($(textareaEl).val()+$(inputEl).val()+"\r\n");
        
        //Cleaning input
        $(inputEl).val('');
    }
        
    return false;
}
});

$("#delete").on("click", function() {
  var value = $("#quickLinksTextbox input").val(),
  textareaEl = $('#quickLinksURLs'),
  textareavalue = textareaEl.val().split("\n");
  if(textareavalue.indexOf(value) >= 0) {
      textareavalue.splice(textareavalue.indexOf(value),1);
      textareaEl.val(textareavalue.join("\n"));
      $("#quickLinksTextbox input").val('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="quickLinksTextbox">
 <input>
</div>
<textarea id="quickLinksURLs" rows="5"></textarea>

<button id="delete">Delete</button>
```